# Sequenception: complete five sequences forming a sixth

Tags: logical-deduction, pattern, sequence

[image]

Transcript:

```
SEQUENCEPTION

Use logic to find the missing terms in the sequences below

There are a total of five sequences.
The missing terms of each sequence form another sequence.
Find the sixth term of that sequence.

1. 42 26 15 8  4  _
2. 4  6  8  9  10 _
3. 30 24 27 30 24 _
4. 10 10 20 30 50 _
5. 3  4  33 40 77 _
                  _

SHIVANSH SHARMA
```

Use logic to find the missing terms in the sequences. For any clarification, comment down below.

Answer (score 1):

Partial answer:

> # 1 is the reverse sequence of [A000125](https://oeis.org/A000125) - **2** is the next number

> # 2 is the sequence of composite numbers - **12** is the next number

> # 3 is the sequence formed by cycling through the list [30, 24, 27] - **27** is the next number

> # 4 is the sequence formed by multiplying the Fibonacci numbers by 10 - **80** is the next number

Comment: for the fifth and sixth, I could craft an arbitrary construction that would produce both the given output and any next output I want

Answer (score 1):

> I think the answer you are looking for is 15

> The first four numbers have been explained by teed as 2,12,27,80. The last  number is 150 because 3+4+33=40 4+33+40=77 and so 33+40+77=150

> So the sequence formed as a result, if you look at the digits go as 2+1+2+2=7 7+8+0=15 and so 15+0=15